# Is the quantity $mv^{2}$ also conserved?

Tags: energy-conservation

The following is my reasoning: Suppose $\vec{F}$ is a conservative force field. Then the total mechanical energy, $E$, of the isolated mechanical system is a conserved quantity which implies that $E=T+U=k_{0}$, where $k_{0}$ is a constant, $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is the potential energy. Now, $\nabla{E} =\nabla{(T+U)}=\nabla{T}+\nabla{U}=\vec{0}$. Hence, $\vec{F}=-\nabla{U}=\nabla{T}$. Now, $U=\int_{C} \nabla{T}\cdot d\vec{r}= T+k_{1}$, where $k_{1}$ is a constant of integration. Now, $E=T+U=T+T+k_{1}=k_{0}$ which implies that $E=2T=k_{0}-k_{1}$ is constant and since $T=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$ and hence $E=mv^{2}=k_{2}$, where $k_{2}=k_{0}-k_{1}$ is a constant and therefore $mv^{2}$ is a conserved quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity $mv^2$ is not constant.

You can argue this by an example. Consider a ball in a uniform gravitational field. If you drop the ball, the quantity $mv^2$ changes as it falls, so it's not constant.

Or, more simply, $mv^2$ is twice the kinetic energy. Think of *any* system where the kinetic energy changes, and you've shown that the quantity can't be constant.

So what's wrong with your mathematical argument?

Well, you write $U=\int_C \nabla T\cdot d\vec r$, but that's not true. First, you have a sign error. (Try replacing $\nabla T$ with $-\nabla U$ and you'll see why.) If you correct the sign error, you'd get $U=-\int_C \nabla T \cdot d\vec r = -T + k_1$. Now if you add $T$ to both sides you get $U+T=k_1,$ which at least isn't wrong, but doesn't really gain you anything since $k_1 = E$.

---

The definition of change in potential energy for a conservative force $\vec F_c$ is $\Delta U = -\int \vec F_c \cdot d\vec r$. I suppose you might sometimes see this written without the negative sign, but in that case, the force in the integrand would be the "minimum" force exerted by an *external agent* in order to overcome the conservative force. (This is a sloppy explanation, and best left for a separate Physics.SE question.)

The bottom line is, if you're working with some conservative force field $\vec F_c$, you need the negative sign.

Comment: There is no sign error. By definition $\vec{F}=-\nabla U$ and $-\nabla U=\nabla T$. Please check the definition of the potential energy and force relation.

Comment: $\Delta U=-\int \vec F\cdot d\vec r = -\int \nabla T\cdot d\vec r$. If the conservative force and displacement are in the same direction, then the change in potential energy is *negative*. (Consider a ball being dropped. It moves down, $\Delta U < 0$.) But do try replacing your $\nabla T$ with $-\nabla U$ in your integrand and you'll see a contradiction pop up immediately.

Comment: NO! $U=\int_{C} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$. There is no minus sign as you have pointed out. How can the net force on a particle be opposite the direction of displacement. It does not make sense. Mathematically, we don't care about the displacement of the particle being opposite to the direction of displacement because I am using the fundamental theorem of line integrals.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pegrav.html

Comment: "Consider a ball in a uniform gravitational field" the same thought experiment would 'prove' mv is not conserved.

Comment: I agree it would show that it's not constant for the system of just the ball. But for the ball and Earth, the total momentum is constant.